# pandas invalid literal for long() with base 10 error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, casting, int

I am trying to do:  `df['Num_Detections'] = df['Num_Detections'].astype(int)`

And i get following error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '12.0'

My data looks looks following:

```
>>> df['Num_Detections'].head()
Out[6]: 
sku_name
DOBRIY MORS GRAPE-CRANBERRY-RASBERRY 1L     12.0
AQUAMINERALE 5.0L                            9.0
DOBRIY PINEAPPLE 1.5L                        2.0
FRUKT.SAD APPLE 0.95L                      154.0
DOBRIY PEACH-APPLE 0.33L                    71.0
Name: Num_Detections, dtype: object
```

Any idea how to do the conversion correctly ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is some value, which cannot be converted to `int`.

You can use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and get `NaN` where is problematic value:

```
df['Num_Detections'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Num_Detections'], errors='coerce')
```

If need check rows with problematic values, use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask with [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html):

```
print (df[ pd.to_numeric(df['Num_Detections'], errors='coerce').isnull()])
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Num_Detections':[1,2,'a1']})

print (df)
  Num_Detections
0              1
1              2
2             a1

print (df[ pd.to_numeric(df['Num_Detections'], errors='coerce').isnull()])
  Num_Detections
2             a1

df['Num_Detections'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Num_Detections'], errors='coerce')
print (df)
   Num_Detections
0             1.0
1             2.0
2             NaN
```

Comment: exactly this was the issue the string values that cannot converted directly to int.

Comment: yes, the best approach is first check values. And then choose one or another solution.

Comment: To me it makes a MESS to use to_numeric? how it could be?

Comment: @M.Mariscal - `MESS` ? Can you explain more?

Comment: https://imgur.com/E3Q582q, im using to_numeric downcasting to integer, i'm using df["Col1"].astype(int) but no results, its completely a mess, sort doesnt work

Comment: @M.Mariscal - hmmm, there are floats values, not sure if understad, what is expected output?

Comment: Not floats, only thousands, in the pic is order ascending, and as you can see...

Comment: @M.Mariscal - so remove it by `df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace('\.','')` before

Comment: Cannot, is not a string, and the backslash to escape doesnt need it

Comment: @M.Mariscal - it is escaped `.`, becuse special char

Comment: @M.Mariscal - try `df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'\.','')`

Comment: @M.Mariscal - do you try solution before `pd.to_numeric` ?

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '102.314'

Comment: @M.Mariscal - so `df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'].str.replace(r'\.',''), errors='coerce')` not working?

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str' (I tried also with astype(str) but nothing)

Comment: @M.Mariscal - do you use `df['col']`, not `df`, right?

Comment: @M.Mariscal - what return `print (df['col'].columns)` ?

Comment: dtype "objects" i can see

Comment: @M.Mariscal - hmmm, it should raise error, problem is duplicated columns names

Comment: No they aren't duplicated

Comment: @M.Mariscal - Not idea, please post question. It is data related problem.

Comment: df['Total'] = df['Total'].str.replace(r'\.', '') How can i do it for multiple columns? it looks its the problem... i cannot understand that