# How can I check whether a column contains strings in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The codes are below. I want to create a new column "value_c" based on simple operation on column "value".

```
frame['value_c'] = frame['value'].apply(lambda x: (x-32) / (5/9))
```

However, I got an error message like below.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

How can I check whether the column has strings and how can I delete them?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.to_numeric` then `dropna`:

```
frame['value_c'] = pd.to_numeric(frame['value'],errors='coerce').dropna().apply(lambda x: (x-32) / (5/9))
```

Then it will work as expected.

Comment: @hacker315 there are few cases where you cannot `.astype(int)` check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918653/pandas-invalid-literal-for-long-with-base-10-error

Comment: @hacker315 Yeah, anky_91 is correct, you only can do `astype(int)` to string integers

Comment: @YabinDa Happy to help :-)